# I have written a code for merge sort.but I couldn't return sorted value how can I return sorted list

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

I have written two functions for merge sort:

```
def mergesort1(c, l, r):
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
    while (i < len(l)) & (j < len(r)):
        if l[i] < r[j]:
            c[k] = l[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            c[k] = r[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    while i < len(l):
        c[k] = l[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(r):
        c[k] = r[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

def mergesort(c):
    if len(c) < 2:
        return c
    l = c[0 : (len(c) // 2)]
    r = c[len(c) // 2 : len(c)]
    mergesort(l)
    mergesort(r)
    mergesort1(c, l, r)
```

I am unable to return sorted value of my function

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting the list in-place: the result of the sorting is in the original list. If you'd like to return a new list with the result without modifying the original list:

```
def mergesort1(l,r):
    c = [0]*(len(l) + len(r))
    i,j,k=0,0,0
    while (i<len(l))&(j<len(r)):
        if l[i]<r[j]:
            c[k]=l[i]
            i +=1

        else:
            c[k]=r[j]
            j +=1
        k +=1
    while i<len(l):
        c[k]=l[i]
        i+=1
        k+=1
    while j<len(r):
        c[k]=r[j]
        j+=1
        k+=1
    return c

def mergesort(c):
    if len(c)<2:
        return list(c) 
    l = mergesort(c[0:(len(c)//2)])
    r = mergesort(c[len(c)//2:len(c)])
    return mergesort1(l,r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mergesort` function sorts the list in place. You can add a return statement to facilitate method chaining but the function will always return its original argument:

```py
def mergesort1(c, l, r):
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
    while (i < len(l)) & (j < len(r)):
        if l[i] < r[j]:
            c[k] = l[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            c[k] = r[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    while i < len(l):
        c[k] = l[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(r):
        c[k] = r[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

def mergesort(c):
    if len(c) >= 2:
        l = c[0 : (len(c) // 2)]
        r = c[len(c) // 2 : len(c)]
        mergesort(l)
        mergesort(r)
        mergesort1(c, l, r)
    return c
```